# Django - Input values in form not taken - always error "This field is required"

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement djangorestframework as given here
http://django-rest-framework.org/examples/pygments.html

However when I run the code the form for post, does not accept any value even if i fill all the values. All the fields come back with error message "This field is required". Any one has idea why this happens.

Comment: can you put some relevant code fragments here?

Comment: Ran into problems due to set up and routes. Fixed it by starting the app from scratch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If using a file form, you probably forgot to add the enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form template. If so, the FileField in your form is never be valid after a POST.

Should look like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```